# libpcan header files not found, where are they?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, ros-fuerte, ubuntu-precise, care-o-bot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need to compile some C++ with a libpcan.h include. According to the wiki [libpcan is contained within cob-extern](http://www.ros.org/wiki/libpcan) As I am using Ubuntu Precise I installed the ros-fuerte-cob-extern package. However it seems this does not include the required headers.

I then tried installing from the [git repo](https://github.com/ipa320/cob_extern) but I get the following error when running the make file:

`[rosbuild] Downloading https://code.ros.org/svn/release/download/thirdparty/peak-linux-driver-6.24.tar.gz to build/peak-linux-driver-6.24.tar.gz...Traceback (most recent call last): ... File "/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/bin/download_checkmd5.py", line 28, in main urllib.urlretrieve(uri, dest) ... IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol make: *** [build/peak-linux-driver-6.24/unpacked] Error 1`

**Edit**
The SSL error seems to be to do with me being behind a proxy. I hosted the tarball locally and changed the url and that worked.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36786/libpcan-header-files-not-found,-where-are-they?/) by [sjdowling](https://answers.ros.org/users/2649/sjdowling/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-06-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

libpcan is downloading a tarball from code.ros.org. Are you sure you have internet access and code.ros.org is available from your location?

I just did a fresh checkout and successfull build on ubuntu 10.04, 11.10 and 12.04 for electric and fuerte.

---

Originally posted by [weisshardt](https://answers.ros.org/users/1163/weisshardt/) with karma: 106 on 2012-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1